# Perform some action when certain time comes

Tags: java, android, events, time, background

I'm building an Android organizer app.
I have an `Event` class that has a start time and I want to trigger some action when this time comes. So, how can I constantly compare this *start time* with *current time*, to know when it comes?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of constantly checking for current time against scheduleStartTime, you can schedule task to trigger at scheduledStartTime.

You can use either JobScheduler or AlarmManager
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder.html

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-the-jobscheduler-api-on-android-lollipop--cms-23562

You can set when to trigger task by specifying time difference between start time and current time in millisecond.

```
builder.setPeriodic(5000);
```

Or you can also use Alarm manager

https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

```
alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

You could use one of the following solutions :

- Have a time and on Timer tick, you could compare your start time against the current time and trigger you action if needed.
- Or, you could use a ScheduledExecutorService to schedule the task you want to archive x seconds in the future base on the current time and the start time of your Event

As you are on Android, I would recommend to do this as part of a Service.

Hope this will help.